# Safari: how to control where tabs are opened when a link is followed?

Tags: safari, tabs

In Safari, if I press comand+click to follow a link, the new tab is placed in what looks to be some random location among the tabs in my window. I don't understand what algorithm is being used to determine the tab location. Sometimes it's to the far right of all the tabs, sometimes it's immediately to the right of my current active tab, sometimes it's in the middle of my set of tabs in the window. When I have ten or so tabs open and I follow a link and the new tab is opened in what I perceive as a random location, it makes it difficult for me to find the new tab.

My question is: **is there some configuration I can use to make the new tab location consistent?** I don't care what that consistent exactly is: always to the far right, always immediately to the right of the active tab, etc. I just don't want to have to hunt around for the new tab after it's opened. I cannot find any such configuration when I peruse Safari's preferences settings.

Thanks!

Comment: afaik, it opens to the right of either the originating tab or rightmost of all other tabs already launched from that originating tab. That makes it consistent, though not truly predictable.

Comment: excatly like @Tetsujin is saying.